# Moving files between folders based on file name

Tags: java

I tried some code for moving files from one to other folder with some priority(means file with some name should move first).

```
    String choice1="WTDocument";
    String choice2="OEM-Document";
    ArrayList<File> insertOrder1=new ArrayList<File>();
    ArrayList<File> insertOrder2=new ArrayList<File>();
    ArrayList<File> insertOrder3=new ArrayList<File>();

    String baseDir="D:\\vignesh\\MoveFolder";
    String destDir="D:\\vignesh\\MoveFolder\\testFolder";
    File initialLocation=new File(baseDir);


    for(File fileToMove:initialLocation.listFiles()){
        String fileName=fileToMove.getName();
        if(fileToMove.getName().endsWith(".jar")){
        if(fileName.contains(choice1)){
            insertOrder1.add(fileToMove);
        }
        else if(fileName.contains(choice2)){
            insertOrder2.add(fileToMove);
        }
        else{
            insertOrder3.add(fileToMove);
        }
    }
    }
    insertOrder1.addAll(insertOrder2);
    insertOrder1.addAll(insertOrder3);

    Iterator<File> iter=insertOrder1.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        File fileInOrder=iter.next();
        System.out.println("Files moving are--"+fileInOrder.getName());
        File destLocation=new File(destDir+File.separator+fileInOrder.getName());
        FileUtils.moveFile(fileInOrder, destLocation);
    }
}
```

This code can work fine.But my requirement is that priority name can be given as property entry as comma separated values.

Like this

```
String value="WTDocument,OEM-Document,WTPart,EPMDocument";
String[] choice=value.split(",");
for(int i=0;i<choice.length;i++){

}
```

Now my condition I need to validate condition according to `choice[i]` value and put that in arraylist then I have to move those.Here how I have to write condition for multiple choice values?And I need to put those in order and then to move.

Also that folder will have files with different names which has not included in choice and I need to add those at the end of my arraylist.

Please someone suggest me an Idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Map for each choice :

```
Map<String, ArrayList<File>> map = new HashMap...
for(String c : choice)
  map.put(c, new ArrayList<File>());

for(File fileToMove:initialLocation.listFiles()){
  String fileName=fileToMove.getName();
  if(fileToMove.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
    String ch = findChice(fileName);
    if(ch != null) {
      map.get(ch).add(fileName);
    }     
...
}

String findChice(String s) {
  for(String c : choice)
    if(s.contains(c))return c;
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String baseDir="D:\\vignesh\\MoveFolder";
    String destDir="D:\\vignesh\\MoveFolder\\testFolder";
    File initialLocation=new File(baseDir);
    String value="WTDocument,OEM-Document,WTPart,EPMDocument"; 
String[] choice=value.split(",");
for(int i=0;i<choice.length;i++){
    for(File fileToMove:initialLocation.listFiles()){
        String fileName=fileToMove.getName();

        if(fileName.contains(choice[i])){
            insertOrder.add(fileToMove);
        }
    }
}
```

Now inner for loop iterates each file and checks with first choice for first iteration of outer for loop and add them to list, next outer iteration takes second priority and iterates the files with  inner loop and adds only 2nd choice files to list and so on

Comment: The folder may contain files other than these filenames. Your loop is not handling those files

Answer (score 0):

if other files also means files without choice type in a name ? if that is the case then add one else condition inside inner loop as below

Create an arraylist insertOrderLeastPriority for n priority files.

```
for(int i=0;i<choice.length;i++){
    for(File fileToMove:initialLocation.listFiles()){
        String fileName=fileToMove.getName();

        if(fileName.contains(choice[i])){
            insertOrder.add(fileToMove);
        }
else {
insertOrderLeastPriority.add(fileToMove);
}
insertOrder.addAll(insertOrderLeastPriority);
    }
```

and now it should work..

let me know for any issues

Comment: sorry add this line after outer loop  insertOrder.addAll(insertOrderLeastPriority);

Comment: This is adding duplicate elements to the arraylist and when I remove those duplicate objects the order is getting change..?

Comment: can you please check whether u have kept the line insertOrder.addAll(insertOrderLeastPriority); outside the outer for loop because if we keep it inside for loop it gets added with the duplicates..check it and let me know